# Can't split/strip by space in a string in Ruby because it's an NBSP character

Tags: ruby, string, text, ruby-1.9

I have this large XML file. There is a field that I want to split a field by space.

So I do the following to save the splitted data into a & b:

```
components = a.split(' ')
a = components[0]
b = components[1]
```

However some are splitted correctly, but some are not (when they all contain spaces). For example when I try to split `'Maria Canada'` it does not split by space.

I am not sure why. If I open the file in Vim and copy those particular wrong text, I can split them correctly in Ruby interactive shell:

```
'Maria (Canada)'.split(' ')
 => ["Maria","(Canada)"]
```

**UPDATE**

Ok the reason is NBSP. I printed out those lines which doesn't split in the console by raising errors. I copied the text and pasted in irb. These copied text can't be splitted in irb either, nor can I strip that space.

```
>> ' '.strip
=> " "
```

I then run `ord` and found out that the space is a NBSP character (its code is 160):

```
>> ' '.ord
=> 160
```

***So the xml file contains both space and NBSP characters.*** I think Vim auto converts NBSP to spaces, and that's why when I tried to copy it from vim it is not NBSP anymore.

Now I just need to figure out how to deal with NBSP.

Comment: Imagine that you were reading this question without any previous idea of what you are doing. Do you think you can understand what the question is about?

Comment: sorry about that I tried to clarify it a bit

Comment: maybe it's actually a tab char? try a.split(/\s+/) and see if it helps.

Comment: yep tried it but doesn't work either

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should split on all whitespaces, including the non-ASCII ones:

```
a, b = str.split(/[[:space:]]/)
```

I'm assuming you are using Ruby 1.9+ and that your `str` has the right encoding (e.g. utf-8). As explained in the [regex reference](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/re.rdoc), `\s` matches only ASCII spaces, while `[[:space:]]` will match all unicode spaces (same for `\d` vs `[[:digit:]]`, etc...)

Answer (score 5):

When I was processing a lot of XML, I'd encounter similar problems.

Rather than try to remove the NBSP after parsing, sometimes I'd see if they appear in an encoded form in the raw XML and then do a global search and replace before I parsed. Look for `&NBSP;` or `\xa0` or something similar in those positions.

Alternately, you can do a couple of other things:

You can change your split to something smarter:

```
# encoding: UTF-8

NBSP = "\u00a0"

str = "a b\tc#{ NBSP }z"
str.split(/(?:\s|#{ NBSP })+/) # => ["a", "b", "c", "z"]
```

or

```
str.gsub(NBSP, ' ').split(' ')
 => ["a", "b", "c", "z"]
```